# Android KeyCodes for combination of letters

Tags: android, ime

I am implementing a custom input method (softkeyboard ) for android...Its a gesture detection keyboard,so I will capture the direction the users swipes and the code for that.In doing so,I have some combination of letters like "Th" and "Ch" for which I would need the int value.The char values can be easily converted ,but how to get int values for combination of characters...Please suggest.

I need getCharacter(code) to return an int.

Answer (score 0):

Only by successive calls to `getCharacter()`.. take a step back and see that this method is not the best point to be implementing what youre trying to do.  The handler that returns the multiple chars (strings) should implement `getCharacter()` successively on every character in the string.  If I am understanding the problem correctly.

Comment: I am extending developing the code that was written by some one else.In the code ,for every character the user swipes,we retrieve int value for that character inside a method by passing the code and direction. 'getCharFromKey(code,direction)'.My question was if the user enters characters like "Th" which is on the keyboard,there is no way to return an integer equivalent of "Th" that I can retrieve later?